# Concurrent network XML file updates via PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, concurrency

I need to maintain a shared XML file on the network, which will be updated by multiple machines.

My understanding is that
1: There is no native PowerShell or .NET function to maintain an XML file, especially in a concurrent access scenario. And
2: There is no native PowerShell mechanism for locking a file on the network.
So I will need some sort of home grown solution. At the extremes the file might get updated 15-20 times a year by each machine, and it needs to scale to as many as a thousand machines. But the actual amount of data to be written is small, while the other things going on prior can be very time consuming, and variably. And in the vast majority of cases it won't be an en-mass update anyway, more on the order of a few hundred machines at most, updating the file over the course of perhaps even 15-20 minutes. So the chances of multiple machines accessing the file at the same time are remote, but still need to be addressed.

My thought is to have the script running on the machines rename the XML file with the machine name appended. It can then read the XML, modify as needed, write over the previous file, then rename back. 
The script would have a wait loop that looks to see if there is no correct file but there is a renamed file, and wait till the other machine working with the file is done and renames the file back before proceeding with it's own efforts. The machine scripts will be initiated as remote jobs from a central script, which could stagger the jobs to further reduce the chances of conflicts.

My first question is, am I missing some delightfully better approach? I have to stick with the simple here, I can't get into databases and the like. It needs to be a simple flat file.

And, assuming there is no other obvious approach, are there any major pitfalls or gotchas anyone can see? I am sure I will need to addresses various error conditions, and probably have a fallback of saving the data to individual files for each machine and a separate utility to pull that data into the main file after all the updating is done. But I don't want to have that be the primary workflow if I can help it.

I know, a rather 10,000 foot question, but any insight is greatly appreciated. I have a plan to create a dummy XML file with 1000 records and then run a simple remote script on 3-4 machines that launch at the same moment, and put a timer on the process, so I can see how long each operation takes and if any machine even needed to wait to write. But if I can learn from someone else's mistakes I'd rather. ;)

Thanks,
Gordon

Comment: Hints: [xml]Get-Content, Export-Clixml, ConvertTo-XML... File access contention and locking is build into OS/File System. Use [System.io.File]::Open and check for errors. Good reference is here [Dealing With File Locks](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/06/23/dealing-with-file-locks.aspx)

Comment: Jan, I could have sworn that was one of the web sites I found when I was testing things, and when I ran a script from one machine on a file on a second and locked it, a third machine was able to read and write with no issues, making me think that the entire approach only worked on the local machine. I guess tomorrow I'll be trying that experiment again to see where I went wrong, because a lock like this would certainly save me a ton of coding.

Comment: Well, I may be on to something. It seems like this is a valid approach only when using a Windows machine for sharing? I tested that and it works great, but as soon as I moved the XML file to the Synology NAS where it will really live it stayed locked until I rebooted the NAS. That seems totally not valid, and I have an email in to Synology, but I thought I would check back here and see if there any other other gotchas from a PowerShell standpoint.

Comment: And a follow question, how does one combine the file locking with Get-Content? I can't directly access the file with Get-Content because the file is locked, but if I set the output of [System.io.File]::Open to a variable I can't use that with Get-Content because it isn't a stream.

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. File locking on network shares is a big "bucket of worms". It is implemented in the networking protocols and also on the server site. When you stick with MS products you have one vendor implementing all the components and you have a better chance of everything working together. If you put you file on NAS, you have the vendor's implementation of file locking system to deal with. In this case most likely a version of [SAMBA](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/locking.html).

Comment: I would suggest asking a separate ,more specific question with regards to file locking. There are many knowledgeable people here and sometimes it is easier to get answers when you have a direct question about one specific subject..

Comment: I will try and put together an example script to show how to read an XML file that was opened using  [System.io.File]::Open.

Comment: Jan, indeed, my Synology NAS is using Samba. And since a NAS is a really common solution for the SMB world, where a good 90% of architecture firms sit, depending on Microsoft file locking isn't going to work for me. I have the rename approach working well in testing. next step is to test it scaled up. But looking positive, and I can be sure it will work on whatever odd setup someone might have. I mean, I've seen small architecture firms using AutoDesk Revit in a Windows VM on Macs with a Mac file server! ;) That said, would love to see how the XML with File Lock approach would work.

Comment: Well, the rename approach worked small scale, but when I artificially created a scenario where multiple machines hit the file at basically the same time it fell apart. Basically I had two machines trying to rename the file at the same time. I need to come up with conditions that never produce an erroneous ok to rename. So, if anyone has some thoughts here I would love to hear it. It seems like a problem that has probably been solved, at least to the extent that there is a pattern that addresses it. I hope. ;)